# Unable to execute "TPM 1.2 Update" on Ubuntu (XPS 13 9350): This TPM is Owned

Tags: bios, firmware, tpm

My Ubuntu 17.10 is showing a TPM Update (1.2, 5.81.0.0 -> 5.81.2.1) for a couple of weeks or months now but when I restart the machine it's unable to execute the firmware update successfully.

*Error:*

> This TPM is Owned. Please clear the TPM Owner. This update is not for this system.

Comment: Yes, if the TPM is potentially holding key material, it cannot be updated, because the update could include code to read the key material. That's not a bug, but a feature.

Answer (score 9):

**Attention:** *If you encrypt your disk with TPM the following steps will clear the encryption keys and you'll lose your data (thanks @Simon Richter)! I encrypt my disk with Ubuntu's encrypted home & encrypted LVM and did not lose any data.*

I was able to solve this issue by:

- Reboot the machine and enter the BIOS *(usually by hitting the `F2` or `esc` or `del` key depending on your motherboard)*
- Go to `Security` → `TPM 1.2 Security`
- Enable the `Clear` checkbox to clear the TPM information
- Save & exit the BIOS
- **Install the TPM update again**, after rebooting the update should succeed

Comment: Caveat: if you used the TPM for encrypting your harddisk, this will also clear the encryption keys and you will lose all your data.

Comment: Ubuntu's disk encryption stores the key material on the harddisk, encrypted with a key generated from the passphrase, so the TPM is not used. The downside is that security rests on the length of the passphrase.